# Redundant default gateways on LAN

Tags: routing, gateway, redundancy

I have two default gateways in my network: `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2`. Is there a way to make Windows clients to detect the dead gateway and chnage over to the wowrking one automatically? My gateways are Linux servers. I use Dnsmasq for dhcp. By googling I came to know that a RIP server can be used to do it. But I couldn't get any sample configurations. Can it be done with Quagga or Bird?

Comment: I would recommend using CARP or VRRP instead, if your default gateways support it. Then it will "just work" on all clients without them needing any special configuration.

Comment: By definition, there can only be one default gateway.  David's suggestion would allow the two devices to "share" the one IP (if the primary device fails, the second would assume it's role as the gateway).